# Kivy and Python: How to make asymmetrical graphic of math functions at the same canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, rectangles

all right? i hope so, I will be very grateful if you try to solve this problem that I'm facing about programming.
I'm trying to make a quadratic function plotter, however I can only display one side of the function.
If you uncomment that part of the code you will see that kivy only displays the other side, but the first side of the graphic is still hidden.
What I want to do and if you can help me here is to display both sides of the quadratic function in the same graph and code.
My code is bellow:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
Builder.load_string(
'''
<QuadraticApp>:
    my_size: [root.size[0]*4, root.size[1]*0.5]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0
        Rectangle: 
            pos: (root.pos[0], root.pos[1])
            size:(500, 500)
'''
)
class QuadraticApp(Widget):
    my_size = ListProperty([0, 0])
    def __init__(self):
        super(QuadraticApp, self).__init__()        
        new_y = self.my_size
        new_x = self.my_size 
        #'''
        for x in range(100):
            with self.canvas:                                                  
                Color(0.1, 0.75, 0.1, 1, mode='rgba') # GREEN
                rectx = Rectangle(pos=(new_x), size=(10, 10))                
            new_x[0] += (x*0.25-50)/2
            new_x[1] += eval('(x)**2')  
        #'''
        # Comment the for loop above to hide the another showing graphic
        # And Uncoment this code bellow to show the another part of graphic
        '''             
        for y in range(100):
            with self.canvas:                                                  
                Color(0.75, 0.1, 0.1, 1, mode='rgba') # RED
                recty = Rectangle(pos=(new_y), size=(10, 10))                
            new_y[0] += -(y*0.25-50)/2
            new_y[1] += eval('(y)**2')        
        '''
class MathApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return QuadraticApp()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MathApp().run()
```

This image bellow show the graphic at the left simetric side

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1WTy.jpg

This image bellow show the graphic at the right simetric side

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVhAz.jpg

Now i can say thank you for u support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code:

```
    new_y = self.my_size
    new_x = self.my_size
```

is just creating references to self.my_size, so when you change `new_x`, or `new_y`, or `self.my_size`, you are changing all three. At the start of your second loop, `new_y` starts out with the values from `new_x` from the end of the first loop. Try changing those two lines to:

```
    new_y = self.my_size.copy()
    new_x = self.my_size.copy()
```

Comment: Howwww! very thank you my dear dude, it solved my issue thanks!

Comment: my code yet is incomplete, how we can put a rectangle at the middle of the nearest points and resize then to fill the curve in that dots?